# Unable to install Grails Asynchronous Mail plugin

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-plugin

Grails Version: 3.0.9

Groovy Version: 2.4.5

JVM Version: 1.8.0_60

I'm following the simple instructions to install the Grails Asynchronous Mail plugin but I'm getting the following error message on start up.

http://grails.org/plugins.html#plugin/asynchronous-mail

Can't seem to find a solution to this no matter how much I google and trawl the web.

I'd be very grateful for any insight.

```
ERROR grails.boot.GrailsApp - Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsApplicationPostProcessor' defined in mchq.admin.Application: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor]: Factory method 'grailsApplicationPostProcessor' threw exception; nested exception is grails.plugins.exceptions.PluginException: Failed to initialize class [grails.plugin.asyncmail.AsynchronousMailAttachment] from plugin [asynchronousMail] : grails/gorm/Entity
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1119) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:116) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:462) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686) ~[spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320) ~[spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:52) [grails-core-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:330) [grails-core-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:319) [grails-core-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source) [grails-core-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48) [groovy-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113) [groovy-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133) [groovy-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at mchq.admin.Application.main(Application.groovy:8) [main/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor]: Factory method 'grailsApplicationPostProcessor' threw exception; nested exception is grails.plugins.exceptions.PluginException: Failed to initialize class [grails.plugin.asyncmail.AsynchronousMailAttachment] from plugin [asynchronousMail] : grails/gorm/Entity
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: grails.plugins.exceptions.PluginException: Failed to initialize class [grails.plugin.asyncmail.AsynchronousMailAttachment] from plugin [asynchronousMail] : grails/gorm/Entity
    at org.grails.plugins.BinaryGrailsPlugin.initializeProvidedArtefacts(BinaryGrailsPlugin.java:133) ~[grails-core-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    at org.grails.plugins.BinaryGrailsPlugin.<init>(BinaryGrailsPlugin.java:66) ~[grails-core-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    at grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager.createBinaryGrailsPlugin(DefaultGrailsPluginManager.java:390) ~[grails-core-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    at grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager.findCorePlugins(DefaultGrailsPluginManager.java:377) ~[grails-core-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    at grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager.attemptLoadPlugins(DefaultGrailsPluginManager.java:329) ~[grails-core-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    at grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager.loadPlugins(DefaultGrailsPluginManager.java:239) ~[grails-core-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.initializeGrailsApplication(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy:87) ~[grails-core-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.<init>(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy:78) ~[grails-core-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    at grails.boot.config.GrailsAutoConfiguration.grailsApplicationPostProcessor(GrailsAutoConfiguration.groovy:59) ~[grails-core-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    at mchq.admin.Application.grailsApplicationPostProcessor(Application.groovy) [main/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1426) ~[springloaded-1.2.4.RELEASE.jar:1.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: grails/gorm/Entity
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:677) ~[groovy-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:787) ~[groovy-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:775) ~[groovy-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.grails.plugins.BinaryGrailsPlugin.initializeProvidedArtefacts(BinaryGrailsPlugin.java:131) ~[grails-core-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    ... 38 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: grails.gorm.Entity
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    ... 54 common frames omitted

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Here is a full list of dependencies :

```
dependencies {
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
    provided "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    compile "org.grails:grails-dependencies"
    compile "org.grails:grails-web-boot"

    compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:cache"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:scaffolding"

    compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.0.0.M1'

    compile "org.grails.plugins:mail:2.0.0.RC2"

    compile 'org.grails.plugins:asynchronous-mail:2.0.0.RC2'

    compile "org.grails.plugins:grails-cloudinary:0.3"

    compile 'org.joda:joda-money:0.10.0'

    compile "org.grails.plugins:taggable:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT"

    compile 'org.grails.plugins:geocode:0.3'

    runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.37'

    runtime "org.grails.plugins:asset-pipeline"

    testCompile "org.grails:grails-plugin-testing"
    testCompile "org.grails.plugins:geb"

    runtime 'com.bertramlabs.plugins:less-asset-pipeline:2.6.7'

    testRuntime 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:2.44.0'

    console "org.grails:grails-console"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a hibernate plugin for Grails 3.x.x. You have to use hibernate3, hibernate4 or hibernate5. I've just tested with hibernate4. Also in my applications there is grails-core dependency.

```
compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate4"
```

instead of

```
compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate"
```

Comment: I'll give that a try.  I seem to recall that the reference to 'hibernate' was created automatically way back when the project was initially created by grails setup....  Are there any major implications/considerations to take into account by switching versions of hibernate?  I'll give a go in test and report back also.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't known. When I create a project it has dependency by hibernate4. Anyway I recommend to upgrade Grails version to the latest. Also you can see [the sample application](https://github.com/kefirfromperm/grails-asynchronous-mail-sample) to check all dependencies.